# Artifact available in <dependencyManagement> but not in <dependency>

Tags: maven, dependencies, dependency-management

I want to add a set of third party jars to my individual maven project POM. The third party gave me a jar which has all the set of required dependencies. I added it into my  but still its not pulling all the third my jars to my .m2 repository folder.

I tried mvn clean build and Maven > Update Project multiple times. Not sure if it is mentioned in  and not , will it be pulled? Also, I checked through pom's dependency hierarchy but the dependency which I added in  is not there. How to deal with this issue? Any help is appreciated! Let me know if any further info is required in this scenario.

Comment: can you share the pom you are using and the groupId/artifactId from the jar that was provided to you? if you add it into dependencyManagement you only define preferred versions. you need to add it into the dependencies section.

Comment: @wemu can you tell me if a dependency is added to <dependencyManagement> and not in <dependency> then will it be pulled?

Comment: well your start would be this: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html - in your case just stick to the dependency section and dont bother yet with dependencyManagement